# I want to print the value of the array according to the key

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently creating a notification list, and I want to print out the date and the notification list that came on that date in ExpansionTile. I sprayed the key value date, but I don't know how to print the value value. I'd appreciate your help.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtxNc.png

```
`Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  "20230701": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230701"},
  ],
  "20230702": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230702"},
  ],
  "20230703": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230703"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230703"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230703"},
  ],
  "20230704": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230704"}
  ],
  "20230705": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230705"},
  ],
  "20230706": [
    {
      "gubun": "alim",
      "message": "false",
      "reg_date": "20230706"
    },
    {
      "gubun": "alim",
      "message":
          "complete",
      "reg_date": "20230706"
    }
  ],
  "20230707": [
    {
      "gubun": "alim",
      "message": "complete",
      "reg_date": "20230707"
    }
  ]
};`
```

Comment: Please add the code you wrote for the listview of the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `Map<String, dynamic>` to `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>` for more convenience in creating widgets and iterating.
You can also view the code at [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=49d0483eb3edc09a862e585ae3a70caf)
Here is the example code based on your code from my new `main.dart` file.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> data = {
  "20230701": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230701"},
  ],
  "20230702": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230702"},
  ],
  "20230703": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230703"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230703"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230703"},
  ],
  "20230704": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230704"}
  ],
  "20230705": [
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "complete", "reg_date": "20230705"},
    {"gubun": "alim", "message": "false", "reg_date": "20230705"},
  ],
  "20230706": [
    {
      "gubun": "alim",
      "message": "false",
      "reg_date": "20230706"
    },
    {
      "gubun": "alim",
      "message":
      "complete",
      "reg_date": "20230706"
    }
  ],
  "20230707": [
    {
      "gubun": "alim",
      "message": "complete",
      "reg_date": "20230707"
    }
  ]
};

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme
              .of(context)
              .colorScheme
              .inversePrimary,
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView(
            children: data.entries.map((e) {
              return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(e.key),
                children: e.value.map((e) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Column(
                      children: e.entries.map((e) {
                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(e.key), const Text(':'), Text(e.value)
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }).toList()
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it at home later

Comment: I did what you taught me, and it turned out well. Thanks, man. @Mearaj

Comment: Hi @sopu5555, I am glad it helped. If you believe that this answers your question, could you please upvote(optional) and mark this as answered? Thanks :)